# Advanced Probability Theory: Understanding Notation for Sequences of Random Variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of random variables, X a random variable, and let $\{X_n\} \rightarrow X$ a.e.

Let $A_m(\epsilon)$ be the event:

$A_m(\epsilon)  = \bigcap_{n=m}^{\infty} \{|X_n-X| <\epsilon\}$

I see this type of notation alot, and I am a bit confused.  Can we think of $\{|X_n-X| <\epsilon\}$ as the sequence $\{|X_n-X|: |X_n-X| <\epsilon\}$, which is the collection of random variables $|X_n-X|$ such that $|X_n-X|<\epsilon $ for all $\omega \in \Omega$.

Let me know.  Help with advanced probability theory notation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\{ |X_n - X | < \epsilon \}$ is the event that $X_n$ is within $\epsilon$ of $X$. It is a subset of the sample space.

Comment: It was suggested by another source that I think of it as $\{\omega: |X_n (\omega)-X(\omega)|< \epsilon, \omega \in \Omega \}$.  If this incorrect, or if someone has a better more detailed example, please post :)

Comment: Yes, that's correct.